# How to iterate through a list with a value from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have a list with different values and a dictionary with different equations. I want to iterate with a `for`-loop through the list values and calculate a given equation. The example is below:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5]
d ={"equation1": 2*x+3,
    "equation2": 3+4*x}

for x in list:
    y= d["equation1"]
    print(y)
```

the output is as you can see below:

```
5
5
5
5
5
```

When I put the dictionary into the `for`loop like the sample below, the right values are calculated:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5]


for x in list:
    d ={"equation1": 2*x+3,
        "equation2": 3+4*x}
    
    y= d["equation1"]
    print(y)
```

Result:

```
5
7
9
11
13
```

How can I realise the right results with the dictionary outside the `for`-loop?

Comment: I think you need more dictionaries or at least more keys

Comment: d ={"equation1": lambda x: 2*x+3,
    "equation2": lambda x: 3+4*x}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first example:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5]
d ={"equation1": 2*x+3,
    "equation2": 3+4*x}
```

This can only work if you somehow defined `x` previously, so you probably didn't share all of your relevant code.

Something like `2*x+3` gets evaluated immediately, so if `x == 1`, you'd get the result `5`, as you suggest you do.

You *could* create a `dict` with `lambda` expressions:

```
d ={"equation1": lambda x: 2*x+3,
    "equation2": lambda x: 3+4*x}
```

But I wouldn't recommend it as good code. If you do though, this works:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5]
d ={"equation1": lambda x: 2*x+3,
    "equation2": lambda x: 3+4*x}

for x in list:
    y = d["equation1"](x)
    print(y)
```

Note how on the line `y = d["equation1"](x)` `x` gets passed to the function accessed with `d["equation1"]` - a lambda expression is a simple function and the ones defined in the `dict` expect a single parameter.

A more appropriate solution would be:

```
def equation1(x):
    return 2*x+3


def equation2(x):
    return 3+4*x


xs = [1,2,3,4,5]
for x in xs:
    y = equation1(x)
    print(y)
```

And then if you have reason to refer to your functions with a `dict` from somewhere:

```
xs = [1,2,3,4,5]
funs = {
    'equation1': equation1,
    'equation2': equation2
}
for x in xs:
    y = funs['equation1'](x)
    print(y)
```

Comment: Thank you Grismar. The second solution will be more work as I have more than 10 different equations. I think the first solution will be more suitable to realize it.

Comment: The extra work would mostly consist of typing "def", "return" and an extra `dict`, while it would have benefits in debugging later, as you'll be able to tell where errors are caused. https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/assigning_a_lambda_to_a_variable.html  However, you are of course in charge of your own code - I just wanted to point out that it's generally considered a bad idea for good reasons. Other reasons include the inability to include more complex logic, recursion, temporary variables, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that the expressions `2*x+3` and `3+4*x` aren't something you can store in a dictionary. Rather, they get computed immediately, with whatever value of `x` is available when the dictionary is created. They do not use the value of `x` when the value gets looked up later.

If you want to store some code, like those expressions, to be run later, the natural way to do it in Python is using a function. The `lambda` keyword even lets you create functions that only evaluate a single expression, which is exactly what you want.

Try:

```
d = {"equation1": lambda: 2*x+3,
     "equation2": lambda: 3+4*x}

for x in list:
    d ={"equation1": 2*x+3,
        "equation2": 3+4*x}
    
    y = d["equation1"]() # note, here we're calling the lambda function
    print(y)
```

A few other notes:

It might make sense to use a different container than a dictionary for `d`, since your equation names don't appear to have a great deal of meaning. If you just want to index them by integer (e.g. `1` instead of `"equation1"`), a list is a much more natural choice.

Also, your equations currently pick the `x` value freely out of the enclosing namespace. It might be cleaner to pass in the `x` value as an argument to the lambda function. Grismar's very nice answer covers how to do this for `x`, so I won't give any redundant example code. Passing the values the equation needs as arguments does require a stricter "contract" to be established between the calling code and the equations though, as if one equation expects there to be a `y` or `z` variable defined, you need to know to pass it in as an argument.

Comment: Thank you for your notes. I have changed the equation names from the real task. I am using different energy technologies as equation names and the equations are describing the costs.  
Since I have already used the dictionary before, I have tried to continue using it.